# Kernel metapackages (linux-generic vs linux-image-generic)

Tags: metapackages

The package hierarchy for Ubuntu kernel images looks like this:

linux-generic --> linux-image-generic --> linux-image-2.6.38-8-generic.

Both linux-generic and linux-image-generic are metapackages. I understand the purpose of having one kernel metapackage (to handle upgrades and multiple kernel versions), but what is the point in the second level? It seems that linux-generic only depends on linux-image-generic, so surely it is redundant?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes it <s>is</s>was. But since Ubuntu 12.10 `linux-generic` depends both on image and headers metapackages:

```
linux-generic ─┐
               ├─ linux-image-generic   ─ linux-image-VERSION-generic
               │                        ┄ linux-image-OLD_VERSION-generic
               │                        ┄ linux-image-ANCIENT_VERSION-generic
               │
               └─ linux-headers-generic ─ linux-headers-VERSION-generic
                                        ┄ linux-headers-OLD_VERSION-generic
                                        ┄ linux-headers-ANCIENT_VERSION-generic
```

But I cannot explain why it was that way over mutiple release cycles. If you look at [Ubuntu package search](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=linux-generic&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all) and look at all versions you will see at least the Hardy `linux-generic` package depends on two meta-packages (-image-generic and -restricted-modules-generic).