# Ubuntu 13.10, kernel still 3.8.0-31-generic

Tags: updates, kernel

I updated from 13.04 to 13.10 but `uname -r` still says I am on 3.8.0-31-generic.
How can i fix this and get 3.11 or 3.12 ?

Comment: open terminal and try this > sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade -y && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade -y

Answer (score 8):

Happened exactly the same, I noticed that now that I had to compile wacom drivers. For whichever reason, the package `linux-image-generic`  was not installed (probably ocurred during the upgrade from 13.04 to 13.10).

```
sudo apt-get install linux-image-generic
```

seems to correct the fact (will modify this if not).

You can also do

```
sudo apt-get install linux-generic
```

to automatically install the kernel headers, too (thanks to Lars Nyström).

(**obviously** if you have -rt or -lowlatency kernels you have to adapt this to your case)

Comment: You could also install linux-generic, which will give you both linux-image-generic and linux-headers-generic (http://askubuntu.com/a/197615/162987). I just installed linux-generic and it worked liked a charm!

Answer (score 0):

Fixed.

I downloaded the 3.12 rc6 kernel deb files from [kernel.ubuntu.com](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/) and installed it with `dpkg -i`

Comment: This works, but still is not a fix: you need to upgrade kernels by hand afterward. My solution will put you back on the automatic kernel updates...

Answer (score 0):

You need to first enable the proposed repositories

[image]

[image]

Then enable all 4 update sources and on the Ubuntu Software tab enable all 4 options also. Then update and you should see the 3.11.X

[image]

Do not update to the 3.12.X or the 3.13.X without knowing that you will find weird behaviors related to drivers, boot time and graphical issues. Always use the one in the updates by Ubuntu.

Comment: Kernel 3.11 is standard in 13.10, I think. I have that kernel without need the "proposed"repository. What happened is that during the 13.04->13.10 upgrade the "linux-generic" metapackage was  not updated, and the kernel stayed at 3.8.

Comment: That is totally correct Rmano. In my case the 2 computers I have here had the same issue and it was solved by doing the steps above. Of course this was for me. Your answer is simpler.

Comment: Seems like a bug in the 13.04->13.10 upgrade procedure...