# Installing the Intuos CTH-480 drawing tablet in a AMR Chromebook

Tags: wacom, chromebook

I am trying to get my Intuos drawing tablet to work on my Chromebook, and since it's not compatible with the Google OS, I chose to install Ubuntu 13.10 and get the drivers.

I did so, and Ubuntu 13.10 is working fine, and I downloaded the kernel driver input-wacom-0.20.0 from http://sourceforge.net/projects/linuxwacom/files/xf86-input-wacom/input-wacom/

Then, I tried to follow the directions found at http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/linuxwacom/index.php?title=Input-wacom

However, I cannot get past the prerequisites section.  For the first step, when I enter:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)
```

it says:

```
E: Unable to locate package linux-headers-3.8-11
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'linux-headers-3.8.11'
```

I know that my kernel is 3.8.11, because when I enter:

```
uname -r
```

I get 3.8.11

Does this kernel not have Intuos support?  I'm very new to Linux, so I don't even know if I am asking the right questions here.  Do I need to set the headers to a kernel that DOES have Intuos support?

Could someone walk me through this?

As I said in my comment,

```
    apt-get install update
```

did not work, so I did

```
    apt-cache search linux-headers
```

This was the output:

```
    linux-headers-3.11.0-12 - Header files related to Linux kernel version 3.11.0
    linux-headers-generic - Generic Linux kernel headers
    linux-libc-dev - Linux Kernel headers for development
    linux-source-3.11.0 - Linux kernel source for 3.11.0 with Ubuntu patches
    linux-headers-3.11.0-12-generic - Linux kernel headers for version 3.11.0 on ARM (hard float) SMP
    linux-headers-3.11.0-12-generic-lpae - Linux kernel headers for version 3.11.0 on ARM (hard float) SMP
    linux-headers-3.5.0-233 - Header files related to Linux kernel version 3.5.0
    linux-headers-3.5.0-233-omap4 - Linux kernel headers for version 3.5.0 on TI OMA p4-based systems
    linux-headers-generic-lpae - Generic Linux kernel headers
    linux-headers-highbank - Linux kernel headers for the armhf architecture
    linux-headers-omap - Linux kernel headers for the armhf architecture
    linux-headers-omap4 - Linux kernel headers for the OMAP4 architecture
    linux-libc-dev-arm64-cross - Linux Kernel Headers for development (for cross-compiling)
    linux-libc-dev-armel-cross - Linux Kernel Headers for development (for cross-compiling)
    linux-libc-dev-armhf-cross - Linux Kernel Headers for development (for cross-compiling)
    linux-libc-dev-powerpc-cross - Linux Kernel Headers for development (for cross-compiling)
    linux-headers-3.0.0-3-maguro - Linux kernel headers for version 3.0.0 on Galaxy Nexus
    linux-headers-3.1.10-6 - Header files related to Linux kernel version 3.1.10
    linux-headers-3.1.10-6-ac100 - Linux kernel headers for version 3.1.10 on Toshiba AC100-based systems
    linux-headers-3.1.10-6-grouper - Linux kernel headers for version 3.1.10 on Nexus 7
    linux-headers-3.11.0-203-exynos5- Linux kernel headers for version 3.11.0 on ARM (hard float) SMP
    linux-headers-3.4.0-1-goldfish - Linux kernel headers for version 3.4.0 on Android touch emulation
    linux-headers-3.4.0-3-mako - Linux kenerl headers for version 3.4.0 on Nexus 4
    linux-headers-3.4.0-4-manta - Linux kernel headers for version 3.4.0 on Nexus 10
    linux-headers-3.4.0-5-chromebook - Linux kernel headers for version 3.4.0 on Samsung Chromebook
    linux-headers-ac100 - Linux kernel headers for the ac100 architecture.
    linux-headers-chromebook - Linux kernel headers for the Samsung ARM Chromebook.
    linux-headers-exynos5 - Linux kernel headers for Exynos5 architecture.
    linux-headers-goldfish - Linux kernel headers for the goldfish kernel.
    linux-headers-grouper - Linux kernel headers for the Nexus7 (grouper).
    linux-headers-maguro - Linux kernel headers for the Galaxy Nexus (maguro).
    linux-headers-mako - Linux kernel headers for the Nexus4 (mako).
    linux-headers-manta - Linux kernel headers for the Nexus10 (manta).
    linux-headers-nexus4 - Transitional package
    linux-headers-nexus7 - Transitional package
    linux-headers-3.11.0-13 - Header files related to Linux kernel version 3.11.0
    linux-headers-3.11.0-14 - Header files related to Linux kernel version 3.11.0
    linux-headers-3.11.0-15 - Header files related to Linux kernel version 3.11.0
    linux-headers-3.11.0-17 - Header files related to Linux kernel version 3.11.0
    linux-headers-3.11.0-18 - Header files related to Linux kernel version 3.11.0
    linux-header-3.11.0-13-generic - Linux kernel headers for 3.11.0 on ARM (hard float) SMP
    linux-header-3.11.0-13-generic-lpae - Linux kernel headers for 3.11.0 on ARM (hard float) SMP
    linux-header-3.11.0-14-generic - Linux kernel headers for 3.11.0 on ARM (hard float) SMP
    linux-header-3.11.0-14-generic-lpae - Linux kernel headers for 3.11.0 on ARM (hard float) SMP
   linux-header-3.11.0-15-generic - Linux kernel headers for 3.11.0 on ARM (hard float) SMP
    linux-header-3.11.0-15-generic-lpae - Linux kernel headers for 3.11.0 on ARM (hard float) SMP
    linux-header-3.11.0-17-generic - Linux kernel headers for 3.11.0 on ARM (hard float) SMP
    linux-header-3.11.0-17-generic-lpae - Linux kernel headers for 3.11.0 on ARM (hard float) SMP
    linux-header-3.11.0-18-generic - Linux kernel headers for 3.11.0 on ARM (hard float) SMP
    linux-header-3.11.0-18-generic-lpae - Linux kernel headers for 3.11.0 on ARM (hard float) SMP
    linux-headers-3.5.0-234 - Header files related to Linux kernel version 3.5.0
    linux-headers-3.5.0-234-omap4 - Header files related to Linux kernel version 3.5.0 on TI OMAP4-based systems
    linux-headers-3.5.0-235 - Header files related to Linux kernel version 3.5.0
    linux-headers-3.5.0-235-omap4 - Header files related to Linux kernel version 3.5.0 on TI OMAP4-based systems
    linux-headers-3.5.0-236 - Header files related to Linux kernel version 3.5.0
    linux-headers-3.5.0-236-omap4 - Header files related to Linux kernel version 3.5.0 on TI OMAP4-based systems
    linux-headers-3.5.0-237 - Header files related to Linux kernel version 3.5.0
    linux-headers-3.5.0-237-omap4 - Header files related to Linux kernel version 3.5.0 on TI OMAP4-based systems
    linux-headers-3.5.0-238 - Header files related to Linux kernel version 3.5.0
    linux-headers-3.5.0-238-omap4 - Header files related to Linux kernel version 3.5.0 on TI OMAP4-based systems
    linux-headers-3.5.0-239 - Header files related to Linux kernel version 3.5.0
    linux-headers-3.5.0-239-omap4 - Header files related to Linux kernel version 3.5.0 on TI OMAP4-based systems
    linux-headers03.11.0-204-exynos5 - Linux kernel headers for version 3.11.0 on ARM (hard float) SMP
    linux-headers03.11.0-205-exynos5 - Linux kernel headers for version 3.11.0 on ARM (hard float) SMP
```

I am looking for one of the header packages for either ARM or exynos, right?  I assume the ones that say Samsung Chromebook?

I did

```
    sudo apt-get install linux-headers-chromebook
```

and then went to the next step. Unfortunately, I got the same problem when I tried

```
    ./configure
```

It completed and read

```
    BUILD ENVIRONMENT: 
    linux kernel - yes 
    kernel source - no

    We could not find the kernel development environment to build the driver.  Please install the kernel source or the kernel development package and try again.
```

There were no other chromebook headers I saw in the list I posted in the pastebin link above.

Maybe the linux-wacom support doesn't work on the Chromebook?

Update with output from

```
    apt-cache search chromebook
```

here:

```
    vboot-kernel-utils - Chrome OS verified boot utils required to sign kernels
    vboot-utils - Chome OS verified boot utils
    linux-headers-3.4.0-5-chromebook - Linux kernel headers for version 3.4.0 on Samsung Chromebook
    linux-headers-chromebook - Linux kernel image for the Samsung ARM Chromebook.
    linux-image-chromebook - Linux kernel image for the Samsung ARM Chromebook
    linux-image-chromebook - Linux kernel image for the Samsung ARM Chromebook.
    linux-tools-3.4.0-5-chromebook - Linux kernel version specific tools for version 3.4.0-5
```

Update with output of

```
    dpkg --get-selections | grep -i chrome | grep -v deinstall
```

here:

```
    linux-headers-3.4.0-5-chromebook                       install
    linux-headers-chromebook                               install
```

Update with output of

```
    dpkg --get-selections | grep -i linux | grep -v deinstall
```

here:

```
    libselinux1:armhf                                      install
    linux-headers-3.4.0-5-chromebook                       install
    linux-headers-chromebook                               install
    linux-libc-ev:armhf                                    install
    util-linux                                             install
```

Comment: Notice that `sudo apt-get install update` is wrong, it's `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get upgrade`...

Comment: I see now.  Well, I'm going to try your updated method.  Install image.  Install headers.  Update Upgrade.  Reboot.  Compile the drivers.  As you said, it could be dangerous, but I think it's worth a shot.  I'll make sure to update again with the results and comment here.

Comment: Unfortunately, after following those directions, I still got the BUILD ENVIRONMENT message I posted earlier in the body of the question.  Perhaps this simply does not work with Chromebook yet?  I've heard that in the next Ubuntu (14.04) will have Wacom/Intuos support immediately?  I don't know if that's true, but I certainly hope it is, because I haven't been able to find a solution to trying to get it to run on my Chromebook.

Comment: Notice that you have kernel 3.8.11 and headers for 3.4.0 --- this is the mismatch that need to be corrected. Very strange.

Answer (score 2):

It's possible your package list hasn't been updated. Try running:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)
```

If that still doesn't work, run this command to see other possible packages that may work:

```
apt-cache search linux-headers
```

Update with the results and we'll take it from there.

Comment: Sorry, I hadn't realized you replied until about an hour ago.

Okay,
    sudo apt-get update
did not work, so I tried
    apt-cache search linux headers. The output was pretty long.  Is there anything specific I should look for?

Thanks for the help, by the way.

Comment: Actually, I'll just write out the output, despite it's length, and edit the question with the output.

Comment: Okay, it is posted in the edit to the original question.  Thanks, again.

Answer (score 1):

The kernel headers must be matched to your running kernel because otherwise you can't compile the driver (kernel module) for you kernel.

I had a similar problem with old kernels hanging around; that meant that there where no headers in the distribution matching the running kernel. There is [one relevant question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/364156/ubuntu-13-10-kernel-still-3-8-0-31-generic) that suggested to reinstall your relevant metapackage for the kernel (in a normal installation is `linux-generic`, I am not sure about a Chromebook. Maybe it is `linux-headers-chromebook`?).

Given the list of packages, I would try (but this could be dangerous... I am not expert of chromebook)

```
sudo apt-get install linux-image-chromebook linux-headers-chromebook 
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

and then reboot *before* compiling the drivers. My doubt here is that I do not see in which package is the kernel you are running now... there should be a `linux-chromebook` metapackage that solves the problems for you.

After that, you can try to follow my answer here: [Wacom Graphics Tablet CTH-480 / CTL-480 Not Detected In Ubuntu 13.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/368242/wacom-graphics-tablet-cth-480-ctl-480-not-detected-in-ubuntu-13-10)

Comment: Oh, funny enough, I actually viewed your answer before.  That's how I figured out where to get the drivers for the tablet from, so thanks for that.  Unfortunately, when I tried to follow the other directions, it yielded the same

        E: Unable to locate package linux-headers-3.8-11
        E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'linux-headers-3.8.11'

Comment: Try to see if there is some package like `linux-chromebook` or `linux-generic-chromebook` with `apt-cache search`.

Comment: There are several, actually.  I printed the output apt-cache search in the pastebin link that is in the body of my question.  Right here: http://paste.ubuntu.com/7091236/  Do you know which one I should use?  Or should I just play around with their compatibility?

Comment: I did 'sudo apt-get install linux-headers-chromebook' and then went to the next step.  Unfortunately, I got the same problem when I tried './configure'  It completed and read 'BUILD ENVIRONMENT: linux kernel - yes kernel source - no'  There were no other chromebook headers I saw.  Maybe the support doesn't work on the Chromebook?

Comment: I put updates in response to what happened in the body of the question.  Basically what I outlined in my comment.

Comment: Please add in another pastebin the output of `apt-cache search chromebook`, of `.dpkg --get-selections | grep -i chrome | grep -v deinstall` and `dpkg --get-selections | grep -i linux | grep -v deinstall`. It seems that you installed the headers but they are not the same of your running kernel, so it does not work.

Comment: I put the outputs in updates in the body of the question in the order you requested them.  Thanks again for all your help!

Comment: Sorry for the delay --- I commented on the question. Had somehow lost this question...