# Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 3.8.0-37-generic (x86_64)

Tags: 12.04, apt, kernel, dkms, afs

After updating some packages in my machine (using `aptitude`), I got the following error:

```
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 3.8.0-37-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/openafs/1.6.1/build/make.log for more information.
```

just after prompting

```
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/header_postinst.d/dkms 3.8.0-37-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.8.0-37-generic
```

I have consulted the log file. The first error I've noticed there was at line 458, and this was it:

```
/var/lib/dkms/openafs/1.6.1/build/src/afs/afs_osi.h:14:21: fatal error: h/param.h: No such file or directory
```

This error has caused the compilation to terminate and the script to exit with error code 2.

Other than that, update went ok. In addition, inside aptitude I don't see any leftovers of packages to be installed (it says "No packages are scheduled to be installed, removed, or upgraded"). So my question is this: should I worry? Did anything really went wrong with the update? If so: what should I do to fix it?

**Edit:** output of `uname -srvmpio`:

```
Linux 3.8.0-36-generic #52~precise1-Ubuntu SMP Mon Feb 3 21:54:46 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

This is ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS.

## Update

I thought that installing `linux-generic` has solved the problem. It looked like that on the first place, but after more than a week, having `linux-generic` still installed, I got the following error on system update, which is almost the same as the old one:

```
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 3.8.0-38-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/openafs/1.6.1/build/make.log for more information.
```

Again, line 458 has showed this error:

```
/var/lib/dkms/openafs/1.6.1/build/src/afs/afs_osi.h:14:21: fatal error: h/param.h: No such file or directory
```

so I tend to believe the problem is somewhere else.

Comment: You did not state your version of Ubuntu. Anyway, check if your problem is http://askubuntu.com/a/387316/16395

Comment: It is indeed possible that this was the problem, thanks.

Comment: If this was the problem please confirm it --- you can add an answer yourself for example.

Comment: So finally it looks like this wasn't the problem. I don't know what the problem is, but this error persists.

Answer (score 1):

The version of the OpenAFS client in 12.04.4 does not support the kernel in 12.04.4. See [bug 1206387](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openafs/+bug/1206387). Specifically, OpenAFS 1.6.1 does not support Linux kernel 3.8, and the relevant patches to make it support that kernel have not been cherry-picked to the official package in precise.

As a workaround, I believe you can use this [OpenAFS PPA](https://launchpad.net/~openafs/+archive/stable).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

Generic:

```
sudo dkms remove <module>/<version#> --all
```

specific example:

```
sudo dkms remove openafs/1.6.1 --all
```

After the above steps, upgrade to the new Linux-Generic header.

```
sudo apt-get install -f --reinstall linux-headers-generic
```

Reboot the system. Once logged in via the new header, install your openafs back into the system. Note: you may experience compatibility issues as mentioned above.

Warn: Don't delete your previous Linux header, until you've confirmed that the current one works well.