# Troubles with suspend

Tags: networking, 14.04, xubuntu, suspend, wakeup

I have some troubles with putting my PC in suspend mode.

#### 1. I can't put it to sleep completely

It suspends current session and goes to the log-in screen, it makes all the screens black, but it doesn't actually power down PC nor displays.

#### 2. No network after wake up

After waking up from suspend the network connection is gone, and I can't re-enable it, so I have to reboot my machine. When I do `ifconfig` I can see that all interfaces are gone. Only `lo` is present.

#### 3. Wake up delay

When it wakes up, it shows me a desktop background without any windows or icons. No keyboard or mouse interactions seems to work. After some time (couple of minutes), everything appears back and seems to work fine apart from issues stated above. I think it is somehow related to running `VirtualBox` virtual machines (via `Vagrant`). When I have no virtual machines running - I'm not experiencing this issue. Also, if I have a running machine I can't shutdown my PC completely. It just hangs in there trying to shutdown until I press a power button on it's chasis.

---

### UPDATE #1:

I've generated log-files requested by @Xubu-Tur.

Here's the list of performed actions:

- Logs cleared
- System shutdown
- System boot
- Log in
- Suspend
- Wakeup
- Log in
- (no network, no delay)
- System reboot
- System boot
- Log in
- Vagrant up (virtual machine booted)
- Suspend
- Wakeup
- (no network, no delay)
- Logs saved

Here's the actual logs:
https://gist.github.com/slavafomin/247b77c5886f2009e56b

I have not encountered third issue this time. Don't know why though.

Please advise.

---

## UPDATE #2:

I've updated my Linux Kernel to the latest version:

```
$ uname -r
3.13.0-24-generic
```

Thank you for suggestion! But I still have the same issues (#1 & #2).

---

I'm using latest `Xubuntu 14.04` on [`ASUS P8P67 EVO REV 3.0`](http://www.asus.com/Motherboards/P8P67_EVO/) desktop computer.

By the way, when running `Windows 8.1` on the same machine (dualboot) I'm not experiencing any of this issues.

I will be glad to update my question with some diagnostic info on request. Thank you!

Comment: The suspend problem exits only if a virtual machines is running? Can you add the `/var/log/pm-suspend.log` and the  `/var/log/syslog` (containing a suspend) please.

Comment: Hello @Xubu-Tur! Thanks for your feedback. I do believe that third issue is dependent on existence of running virtual machine. Without VM there is no wake-up delay. I will provide you with requested log-files at the first opportunity.

Comment: @Xubu-Tur I've updated my question. Can you elaborate please?

Comment: First thing is the Linux version that you use is not up to date `3.11.9-031109-generic` . The current in 14.04 (Trusty) should be `3.13.0-24-generic`

Comment: Hmm, how did it happen? I always install all updates. How do I update it now?

Comment: I haven't done this but this seems to be a good guide http://www.wikihow.com/Update-Ubuntu-Kernel. Perhaps it is better to make a backup before. Did you update from 13.10 to 14.04? Then it could be the same issue as here http://askubuntu.com/questions/364156/ubuntu-13-10-kernel-still-3-8-0-31-generic . You have the kernel from 13.10 on your 14.04 version.

Comment: Can you do this please: Open a Terminal and type `sudo pm-suspend` if there are some messages post them (before or after wakeup). After wake up from suspend type in a Terminal `dmesg > ~/dmesg.txt` and copy the content of the `dmseg.txt` (should be now in your home folder) to the other logs.

Comment: I've added `dmesg` to the [gist](https://gist.github.com/slavafomin/247b77c5886f2009e56b). When I do `sudo pm-suspend`, computer suspends immidiately and turn off the power. When I wake it up, it wakes up momentarily and network is working. No issues at all. Also, `pm-suspend` has no error messages.

Comment: Ok good to hear. Now it should be possible to isolate the error. To do this please do suspend with the normal menu entry in the panel (to cause the faulty suspend). After wakeup run again `dmesg > ~/dmesg2.txt` then upload it.

Comment: I've updated [the gist](https://gist.github.com/slavafomin/247b77c5886f2009e56b#file-dmesg-gui-suspend). Also, I forgot to mention that I has autogenerated error reports every time I log in after reboot. In the details it says that problem is about: `/usr/share/apport/apportcheckresume`. I don't know how to copy that info from the dialog though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the moment I can't find any relevant errors comparing the dmesg after `sudo pm-suspend` and dmesg after gui suspend.
The gui suspend log suddenly breaks before:

```
PM: Syncing filesystems ... done.
PM: Preparing system for mem sleep
Freezing user space processes ... (elapsed 0.001 seconds) done.
Freezing remaining freezable tasks ... (elapsed 0.001 seconds) done.
PM: Entering mem sleep
```

Perhaps its a permission problem but i don't know enough about the difference between `pm-suspend` and gui suspend.

---

Here are a **workaround** for the problem:

Create a laucher on the desktop with `sudo pm-suspend` as command:

[image]

If you want to run this with password, tick "Run in terminal",
else to get it run without entering a password follow this:

Open a terminal and run `sudo visudo` then go to the end of the file and append this:

```
username hostname = (root) NOPASSWD: /usr/sbin/pm-suspend
```

( More info [How do I run specific sudo commands without a password?](https://askubuntu.com/a/159009/265974) )

[image]

Replace username with your username and hostname with your host (run  `hostname` in a terminal to get it)

Press CTRL+X to exit and save the file.
Then the desktop laucher for suspend should be run without need for a password.

---

Other suggestion:

Start from a new Xubuntu 14.04 DVD or USB run "Try Ubuntu" and then try to suspend with gui. If there is is no problem, probably it should be the best to reinstall Xubuntu.

A workaround for your `apportcheckresume` problem could be  http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2053494&p=12219467#post12219467 (but this only deactivate the messages)

Comment: Thank you for taking a time to help me and for such detailed answer! It's sad that Ubuntu/Xubuntu is not stable enough to upgrade itself correctly without the glitches, but thanks to people like you who are always ready to help. My hat's off = )
It looks like it's a good idea to re-install Xubuntu from time to time between upgrades ))

Comment: Thanks for this detailed answer.  I was just about ask the same question and answer it in the same way.